# email from windows service with attachment

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

I have one windows service in vb.net...Its functionality is to send email to faculty at given time...Now i want to send email to faculty along some attached documents to that email from windows service.
That attached documents is the list of users from DB...
So i want to know can we attached some documents to email send through windows service...
If yes how..?
Plz help 
thanx in advance

Comment: just a suggestion, it would be helpful to include the language you are using in the tags on the post, that we can provide more relevant info for ya!

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a document to an email using a `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` object, along with the `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` classes that I will have to assume that you are already using.

There is an example in the MSDN documentation, it is written in `c#` but demonstrates how these classes are used.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx